# How to use custom commands to build static libraries

Tags: cmake

I maintain a CMake based C++ project that has a dependency to a third party rust library. This rust library has to be compiled into a static C library once before being used in the project. As an extra layer of complexity, this needs to be a universal binary for macOS, so I have to compile it twice for each architecture and combine both builds to a universal binary library using `lipo`.

This worked well using three individual CMake custom targets for each step (building the arm64 and x86_64 version of the library, combining them) and declaring dependencies of these targets, but I wanted to get rid of these intermediate targets that might confuse users. My current approach looks like that:

```
set (RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/resvg)
set (RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}/libresvg.a)

add_custom_command (
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Ext/resvg/c-api
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7 cargo build --release --target aarch64-apple-darwin --target-dir ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}
        OUTPUT ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}/aarch64-apple-darwin/release/libresvg.a)

add_custom_command (
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Ext/resvg/c-api
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7 cargo build --release --target x86_64-apple-darwin --target-dir ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}
        OUTPUT ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}/x86_64-apple-darwin/release/libresvg.a)

add_custom_command (
        DEPENDS ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}/aarch64-apple-darwin/release/libresvg.a ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}/x86_64-apple-darwin/release/libresvg.a
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT_DIR}
        COMMAND lipo -create -output libresvg.a aarch64-apple-darwin/release/libresvg.a x86_64-apple-darwin/release/libresvg.a
        OUTPUT ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT})

add_library (resvg STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties (resvg PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT})
target_include_directories (resvg INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Ext/resvg/c-api)
```

The application target then links against that `revsg` target. Unfortunately, this gives me an error like

```
ninja: error: 'resvg/libresvg.a', needed by 'my_application_target', missing and no known rule to make it
```

From my understanding these custom commands define the rules to make it and I have successfully applied techniques like that before to auto generate source files which are used in the build process.

As a note, I also tried to declare the `resvg` target as an `INTERFACE` library which linked against `${RESVG_LIB_OUTPUT}` instead of declaring it as a `STATIC IMPORTED` library target, which resulted in the same issue.

My question is: Can someone explain to me why it doesn't work with my approach and is there something I can alter to make it work with custom commands? I already have a working solution using custom targets, so I'm not interested in solutions using custom targets.

Comment: You may be out of luck. *Targets* can have dependencies on other targets or files. Custom commands and files cannot. It's in the introduction to [cmake-buildsystem](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html).

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right. I know e.g. a working example where one custom command consumes a `.json` file and calls a utility to convert it into a `.proto` file. A second custom command declares a dependency to the `.proto` file generated by the first command, wraps a call to `protoc` which consumes the .proto file and outputs a set of .cc and .h files. These `.cc` and `.h` files are then declared as sources for a library target, which works great, as soon as the library is compiled, both custom commands are triggered. How does that dependency work but the example from the question not?

Comment: Are you sure there's no custom target involved in your examples to drive the custom commands? I maintain it's not possible but I'd be happy to be proven wrong and learn something new.